# js-interop: Passing javascript object from dart

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm struggling to port javascript to dart..

My problem is how to create javascript object.
original javascript code is

```javascript
  function Beagle() {
    this.argv_ = null;
    this.io = null;
  };
  Beagle.prototype.run = function() {
    this.io = this.argv_.io.push();
  };
```

Now I have `Beagle` object. and it should be `context['Beagle']` maybe?

how can I create javascript obejct?? and with `prototype`?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that `Beagle` should be available at `context['Beagle']`. To create a new instance from Dart you need to use the `JsObject` constructor:

```dart
var beagle = new JsObject(context['Beagle']);
```

Once you do that you can call `run` with the `callMethod` method:

```dart
beagle.callMethod('run');
```

Comment: ok, then how can I create `Beagle.prototype.run` ? does it same rule? `context['Beagle']['prototype']['run'] = new JsObject(...)`? or `prototype` has different rule?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Given the above JavaScript, the Dart I showed you is how you access it. Are you looking to define your JavaScript prototype from Dart? It's doable, but unless there's a very good reason, I'd keep your JavaScript in JavaScript.