# Porting javascript to dart

Tags: dart

I'd like to port this javascript code to dart.

```javascript
 function Beagle() {
    this.argv_ = null;
    this.io = null;
  };
  Beagle.prototype.run = function() {
    this.io = this.argv_.io.push();
  };

 runCommandClass(Beagle);
```

the probleme is
How to create object `Beagle`

How to create prototype object `Beagle.prototype.run`

Comment: Seems to be the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567116 Why do you ask twice?

Comment: previous question is  how to call javascript function from dart. and this one is port javascript code to dart..  Because My bad English, I asked with wrong description..

Comment: I'm porting this code.. https://github.com/sunglim/MyChromeApp/blob/master/app/js/beagle.js it's not easy :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
class Beagle { // 
  Map argv_;
  int io;
  Map portInfo;

  // could make sense to make this a constructor, that depends how the Terminal class uses it (didn't look)
  void run(this.argv_) { 
    this.portInfo_ = JSON.parse(this.argv_['argString']); // not tested
    io = argv_['io'].length;
  }

  void sendString_(String s) { // no idea what the underlines at the end of argv_, sendString_, ... are for
    // ...
  }

  void onRead_(String s) {}

  void onTerminalResize_(int width, int height) {}

  void exit(code) {
    // ...
  }

  void close() {
    // ...
  }
}

var b = new Beagle(); // not translated from the JS source - just added to show how to create a new object from the Beagle class
b.run(argvFromSomewhere);
```

This includes a some guessing about what the intention of the JavaScript code might be.

I prefer using specific types when porting from JavaScript. It helped me a lot finding bugs and understanding the intention. When I guessed the wrong type I get an exception at runtime, then I can reason about why I got an unexpected type and which of my assumptions were wrong.

Comment: I could solve my problem with this answer. Thanks Gunter as always!

Answer (score 4):

This kind of Js code (*function* definition and `prototype` changes) can be ported to **a Dart class**. You can follow these main rules :

- `function Xxxx(){/* js code to init */}` (pseudo Js class) translates to :

```dart
class Xxxx {
  /// constructor
  Xxxx() {
    /* Dart code to init */
  }
}
```

- when you have contructor parameters like in `function Xxxx(param1, param2){/* js code to init */}` you have to create an other constructor with those parameters :

```dart
class Xxxx {
  /// constructor with parameters
  Xxxx(param1, param2) {
    /* Dart code to init with param1, param2 */
  }
}
```

- `Xxxx.prototype.method1 = function(p1, p2, p3){/* js code for method */}` are like methods that have to be translated to :

```dart
class Xxxx {
  // .... other code

  /// method
  method1(p1, p2, p3) {
    /* Dart code */
  }
}
```

To make your code more clear you can also add type annotations on methods and constructors. This is recommanded by the [Dart Style Guide](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/#type-annotations).

> Type annotations are important documentation for how a library should be used. Annotating the parameter and return types of public methods and functions helps users understand what the API expects and what it provides.

For instance :

```dart
class Xxxx {
  /// constructor
  Xxxx(String param1, int param2) {
    /* Dart code to init with param1, param2 */
  }

  /// method
  void method1(num p1, String p2, DateTime p3) {
    /* Dart code */
  }
}
```

Comment: If I use pure dart class, I cannot pass that class to `runCommandClass(Beagle);`. Because `Beagle` is dart class. not a javascript function